# How to access google kubernetes engine service from a client

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I set up a kubernetes cluster on GKE that runs a UDP game server. How do I ask kubernetes to start a new container from a game client, and how do I then get the ip address and port of that container so I can communicate with the server from the client.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a service in Google Kubernetes Engine and can be accessed by public IP address. You can create a load balancer autoscaler service which internally takes care of creating new containers when there is increase in traffic.

Here are some documentation for creating [service to access cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps) and creating a [load balancer service](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/udp-with-network-load-balancing).There are other equivalent ways to start new pods on demand using [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/).

You can get IP address by using this command: `kubectl get pods -o wide`